# reboot stuck on "[1534.028775] Restarting system"

Tags: reboot

I just did a fresh install of 13.04, after hearing great comments from people.
The experience was great overall, but the only problem I have is that while rebooting, a black terminal-styled reboot comes up. All tasks had [OK] checked behind it, I'm just stuck on the "Restarting system..." so I ALWAYS have to do a hard reboot using power button. However, shutdown works just fine.

I am using a 64-bit Windows 7 dual boot config and using a **Acer Aspire V3-471G**. Any answer or solution will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: as long as you don't have this problem solved, you can reboot with magic SysRq and typing [r], [e], [i], [s], [u], [b]. This way you won't have to hardware reset your machine. See more on this here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key#Uses

Comment: @onse This partially solved my problem, but is there any way that you can reboot from the UI and not using SysRq?

Comment: there should be. This is just a workaround so that your machine does not get damaged by hardware resetting. The problem is that there can be many reasons why this happens. I would advice you to check your `/var/log/syslog` and `/var/log/kern.log` to see if any errors are being logged when the system won't reboot.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

at terminal :

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Find the line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=””
```

and replace it by this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=”reboot=efi”
```

Save the changes and close the file.

```
sudo update-grub
```

Then try to restart.

Found this solutions at this website :

https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/bugs#TOC-Reboot-fails

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to update. it should be : GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=”reboot=bios”